# Enable/disable two HID keyboards Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, hid

Is there any keyboard manager software for two different HID keyboards or a simple way to disable/enable each one of them at a time without disconnecting the other in Windows 10?
My Device Manager shows 5 HID keyboard entries when I have only 2 keyboards attached and from there I can only uninstall a keyboard and not disable it. Is this ok for temporary work and which keyboard should I use if I have to go that route? I don't want to mess too much with my drivers scheme.
Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to disable a keyboard?  You can leave both keyboards attached and have them both work at the same time.  Are you seeing the 5 entries in Device Manager under > Keyboards or > Human Interface Devices? (screen cap might be helpful)

Comment: I see the 5 entries under Keyboards. Under HID things are vague about controllers.  I want to disable -enable each keyboard because I want to avoid accidental entries.

Comment: With the Keyboard entries in Device Manager, it's fairly safe to just uninstall all the devices (do not delete the driver software though), then Action >  Scan for hardware changes.  The keyboards still attached will automatically repopulate in the Keyboards list.  I don't think there's a software way to disable/enable keyboard devices because a user could potentially lock themselves out of their computer if the OS is programmed to ignore the keyboard.  If you don't want both keyboards usable at the same time, you could look into getting a USB switch to switch between keyboards.

Comment: Thanks for that. I went the switched Usb hub way and I'm happy so far.